Why is it that all major scales are formulated this way?
Why is it that major scales are formulated by starting from an arbitrary note and going, TTSTTTS? Aren't there other ways to make the music sound happy? Why don't we use those? And why don't we just pick the happiest sounding version of that scale and say, 'oh, this is the A major scale'?

In addition to asking multiple related, but different questions, most if not all of them have been answered elsewhere on this site.

Major and happy are not the same thing and I don’t know why people keep thinking they are

A major scale is just a type of scale that is defined that way, TTSTTTS. But it is not the kind of scale that decides whether music is happy or not. It is how the music is composed. A famous example of a piece of music based on a major scale but not happy is "Lascia ch'io pianga" = "Let Me Weep" by Händel. The overall key is major, but there is a B part in minor. You can certainly sense the deep tense emotion from the start in the first part in the major key. Here you can hear Cecilia Bartoli sing this beautuful piece: https://youtu.be/vhpD5JbChPQ?si=PdC5EzaJbmjj76Q4

Another example might be the Alan Parsons song Oh Life (There Must Be More): the verses are in a minor key, and it modulates into the parallel major for the choruses — but they're very much NOT any happier!  (Note: do not listen to this song if you are depressed or sad…)

I read (saw on Youtube?) somewhere that it's all about the perfect fifths.
Consider intervals of fifths with notes of the C-major scale:
   T   T   H   T   T   T   H    <= intervals
[C   D   E   F   G]  A   B   C  => TTHT = 3 whole tones and one semitone
 C  [D   E   F   G   A]  B   C  => THTT = ditto (but slightly re-arranged)
 C   D  [E   F   G   A   B]  C  => HTTT = ditto again
 C   D   E  [F   G   A   B   C] => TTTH (perhaps you see a pattern emerging)

Wrapping over to the next octave,
   T   T   T   H   T   T   H    <= intervals
 F  [G   A   B   C   D]  E   F => TTHT again
 F   G  [A   B   C   D   E]  F => THTT again

But, this pattern breaks down with B-natural:
   T   T   T   H   T   T   H    <= intervals
 F   G   A  [B   C   D   E   F] => HTTH is an interval 1 semitone short

Because the C-major scale, as currently used, has all these perfect fifths, and it makes writing melodic and harmonic music easy.
The note B-natural seems to have historically been problematic for this break in the pattern; this explains why some countries use B♭ and B♮, whereas others use B and H.  See also Why is note B marked with H in Scandinavia and Germany? and also this Wikipedia page.
Also note that the above interval pattern holds true for music in keys other than C-major (with the appropriate key signature used, of course).

Every mode of the major scale, including the natural minor scale, also has the same number of perfect fifths.
